# How to decode a codable object from another init method in that object

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I have a `Codable` type in swift with an init method that accepts the json `Data` that's being called from code I don't control. Can I use this `Data` to automatically deserialise that object?

```
class SomeType : Codable {
  // From this init I want to call into the auto generated `Decodable` init method 
  // with a decoder that can decode the passed in `Data`
  convenience init(data: Data) {
    // This is the imaginary code I'm looking for below
    let decoder = JSONDecoder(for: data)
    self.init(from: decoder)
  }
}
```

Is something like this possible? Codable has auto implemented encode/decode for me and I would like to use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a struct, then @vadian's answer works.

If you need reference semantics for some reason, you could wrap your data class with an adapter that aligns with the interface of your caller.

Depending on how you want to handle errors (return optional or throw), you would implement different init(data:) methods.

If your caller can catch the error, you might do something like this:

```swift
class AdapterType {
    let someType: SomeType

    init(data: Data) throws {
        self.someType = try JSONDecoder().decode(SomeType.self, from: data)
        // ... add do/catch/throw if you need to remap the error for your caller
    }
}

let jsonData = """
{"name":"Foo",\"id":12}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let result = try? AdapterType(data: jsonData)
print("\(result?.someType.name ?? "(unset)")")
```

If your caller doesn't care why the call failed and can handle a returned optional, you can use a failable initializer, like this:

```swift
class AdapterType {
    let someType: SomeType

    init?(data: Data) {
        guard let someType = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SomeType.self, from: data)
        else { return nil }

        self.someType = someType
    }
}

let jsonData = """
{"name":"Foo",\"id":12}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let result = try? AdapterType(data: jsonData)
print("\(result?.someType.name ?? "(unset)")")
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer because its the solution I ended up with in the end because I needed reference semantics. The solutions below by vadian and PGDev are great if you can use a struct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but you have to hand over the error to the caller otherwise you get a compiler error about not having initialized the stored properties.

```
struct SomeType: Codable {

    let name : String
    let id : Int

    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(SomeType.self, from: data)
    }
}

let json = """
{"name":"Foo","id":12}
"""

let result = try! SomeType(data: Data(json.utf8))
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, TIL you can assign self in a struct constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Try using **`struct`** instead.

```
struct SomeType: Codable {    
    init(data: Data) {
        do {
            self = try JSONDecoder().decode(SomeType.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can parse the `data` like,

```
let response = SomeType(data: data)
print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, TIL you can assign self in a struct constructor.